# why My katalon studio not detecting element of my web page?

Tags: automation, katalon

I want to automate my test cases but katalon studio not detecing my browse file element in webpage. thats why i am unable to automate testcases.[that is my webpage screenshot there is browse option i am unable to add that because it is not detecting in katalon studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ujlh.jpg)